# Codeigniter base_url() difference

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**What is the difference of this two codes?**

Are these codes really all the same?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
```

Comment: There is no such PHP function as `base_url`, so I edited the question title to "Codeigniter". You really should read their documentation first…

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the do produce the same result, although I would argue the second line in your example is the best method because it gives you more control when if and when you move to an asset manager of some kind.

Run in latest version of CodeIgniter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://your-domain.org/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://your-domain.org/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Will it be the same when uploaded on web hosting? Because I'm currently using it on localhost.

Comment: The base_url function will create a URL to your BASEPATH (index.php). It should be fine no matter what server you put it on.

Comment: @Craig is right. You set that URL in `index.php` or it will default to whatever URL is being used to call the page.